# What does GraphQL do that REST can't do?

Tags: rest, graphql

I've been seeing that GraphQL allows the user to limit the data they receive, but that can be quite easily done on a REST API.

You can have a, for example, `/users` endpoint that takes a `query` array in the request body, that limits the columns returned from the server.

Or is there something else I'm missing?

EDIT: AS a disclaimer, I'm not asking for an opinion on which one is better. I'm asking for concrete things GraphQL does that REST cannot.

Comment: Is this really opinion based?

Comment: It's frequently the case with programming technologies that you *can* achieve the same thing with different approaches - famously, a large class of problems can be solved by any "Turing complete" language, however simple or esoteric. What varies is things like "how easy it is to implement", and "how expressive it is to use", which tend to be fairly subjective. So I think this is "opinion-based" in the sense the site guidelines are talking about: it's likely to lead to a *discussion* about those qualities, rather than a concrete answer - the responses so far certainly demonstrate that to me.

Comment: @IMSoP - Ah ok, I can see how it would start a discussion. Thanks for explaining it :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you're absolutely right; in REST, you can design an endpoint that accepts query parameters or request headers to control what data you receive in the response. But there are still some key differences that makes GraphQL better:

1. Over-fetching: In REST, the server might still include extra data in
   the response that the client doesn't need, resulting in
   over-fetching. With GraphQL, you can be more precise and avoid this
   problem.
2. Multiple Endpoints: In a large and complex REST API, you might need
   to create many custom endpoints, making it challenging to maintain
   and document. GraphQL uses a single endpoint for all queries, which
   is easier to manage and explore
3. Complex Queries: GraphQL allows clients to express more complex
   queries and request deeply nested data in a single request, making
   it more intuitive for clients to fetch related information.
4. Real-time Updates: GraphQL has built-in support for real-time
   subscriptions, which is not a standard feature in REST.

So, while it's possible to make REST more flexible using custom endpoints and query parameters, GraphQL is designed from the ground up to provide this flexibility and efficiency in a more intuitive way, especially for complex data retrieval scenarios.

Comment: Point 2 is particularly dubious - once you've got a decent framework in place, adding a new entity will take basically the same effort whether you're exposing it as a REST endpoint or a GraphQL type. Point 1 also seems to contradict the previous sentence: since you can include filters, it doesn't need to over-fetch.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that it is possible to limit the data returned by a REST API by including a query parameter in the request. However, GraphQL offers a number of advantages
Here is an example of a GraphQL query to fetch a user's name and email address:

> ```
> query {   user(id: 1) {
> name
> email   } }
> ```

Here is an example of a REST API request to fetch the same data:

```
GET /users/1?fields=name,email
```

As you can see, the GraphQL query is more concise and easier to read. It is also more flexible, since you could easily add additional fields to the query without having to modify the request.

I hope I have answered your question properly

Comment: Your two examples are almost exactly the same length, so make a poor illustration of one being more concise than the other.

Answer (score 0):

There are some key differences that make GraphQL more flexible in certain situations. Let me explain with an example:

**REST:**
Imagine you want to fetch information about a book from a library's API. In a REST API, you might have endpoints like these:

To get the book's title: `GET /books/1/title`
To get the book's author: `GET /books/1/author`
To get the book's publication date: `GET /books/1/publication_date`

Each of these endpoints corresponds to a specific piece of information about the book. If you need all this information, you would need to make three separate requests to the server. This can be inefficient, especially if you want more or less data or need data from multiple related resources.

**GraphQL:**

In GraphQL, you send a single query to the server specifying exactly what data you want, and you get back just that data. Here's how it would look:

```
query {   book(id: 1) {
    title
    author
    publication_date   } }
```

In this single query, you ask for the book's title, author, and publication date. The server then responds with all the requested data in a single response.

Comment: But you could easily create a single `/books` endpoint in REST that allows the client to control what data they receive in the request body.

Comment: This is a pretty ridiculous straw man - neither REST nor GraphQL require or prevent you from making bad design decisions like a separate entity type for "title", and your GraphQL example doesn't actually show any relationship lookups, just a single "book" type. If you want to illustrate the relationship functionality that gives GraphQL it's name, you need an example which actually needs to look at two entities - maybe a book's title and it's author's date of birth.